# VBA equal "weird" symbol detection

Tags: vba, equals

this is my first post and I have a question. In the next image [Equal weird symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJGmG.png)
you can find a equal that is not a subscript. Have you ever seen this symbol? and if you did it. Do you know how to detect using VBA a cells that contains this?

Kind Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

That is an underlined underscore. You should be able to detect it because the formatting on that portion of the string is stored in the `Characters` property of that cell, and not the `Value`.

That is, `myWeirdCell.Value.Contains("_")` should still return `True` for that cell.